# React, can't get past no method 'mountComponentIntoNode'

Tags: google-chrome-extension, reactjs

I have a html that looks like this:

```
<head>
  <script src="../js/vendor/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
  <script src="../js/vendor/react.js"></script>
  <script src="../js/jsx/todo.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="ola"></div>
  <script src="../js/popup.js"></script>
</body>
```

My todo.js is the compiled version TODO app from http://facebook.github.io/react/ minus the last line.

My last popup.js is:

```
$(function() {
  React.renderComponent(TodoApp, document.getElementById('ola'));
})
```

But the page shows nothing! The console shows an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function (props, children) {
      var instance = new Constructor();
      instance.construct.apply(instance, arguments);
      return instance;
    } has no method 'mountComponentIntoNode' react.js:10052
```

I really don't know why is that, I've just tried to recreate from the example in the website. If it matters, it is in a chrome extension.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ahhh got one line wrong on render!

popup.js should be:

```
React.renderComponent(TodoApp(), document.getElementById('ola'));
```

Comment: Good catch. I'll see if we can make a nice warning in React for this specific case.

Comment: I kept getting this error when using `react-test-utils` from npm (with ES6 and babel). My component was valid. I switched to `react-addons-test-utils` from npm and everything magically worked without error.